# How to do multiple clicks with .trigger()?

Tags: jquery, triggers, onclick, click

Is there a simplier way to do this in `jQuery`?

```
$('button').click(function() {
    // do something
}).trigger('click').trigger('click').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve, as I can almost guarantee you there's a better way than this.

Comment: I want to add three divs into another. I have the 'addDiv' function what do this, and I want to run this function multiple times. Three is only a number for example, it is various.

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < timesToRun; i++) addDiv();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding [A. Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff)'s comment, There is no in-build method in jQuery/js to trigger event X times. But, you can pass parameters to the `trigger()`, if you know. So pass the times there:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    // do something
}).trigger('click', 3);
```

Or, for just one `<div>`:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    // do something
}).trigger('click')
```

And then handle this in the `// do something` code block! It could be something like:

```
$('button').click(function(event, times) {
    times = (times == undefined) ? 1 : times;
    for (i = 0; i < times; i++)
       addDiv();
    // do something
}).trigger('click', 3)
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("a").click(function (e, t) {
    t = (t == undefined) ? 1 : t;
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
      $("#testarea").append("Clicked<br />");
    return false;
  }).trigger('click', 3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Click Me</a>
<div id="testarea"></div>
```